# Automatic Differentiation in Drake

Tags: drake

I have a question regarding automatic differentiation (AD) in Drake. If someone writes the DAE for a system in python, how does Drake compute the derivatives for optimization? Does it have a AD package at the backend or it uses finite differences. Also, how does it implement integration and differentiation for quaternion representation. Thanks a lot for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> how does Drake compute the derivatives for optimization

Drake uses Eigen's autodiffscalar type which does automatic differentiation (not the finite difference approach). If you are familiar with the deep learning research, then pytorch's implementation on backward propagation using pytorch tensor object is an example of automatic differentiation (AD). Eigen's autodiffscalar is another example of AD, although not through backward propagation (it uses only the forward pass).

BTW, to create a dynamical system in python, you could refer to this tutorial https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/dynamical_systems.ipynb

> Also, how does it implement integration and differentiation for quaternion representation.

I suppose you mean a time-integral of quaternions. There are two parts of the story:

1. In simulation, we take small steps of the quaternion. We don't project the integrated quaternion back to the unit sphere. On the other hand, we do all the kinematics computation using the transformation matrix in SE(3). So when we convert the quaternion to the transformation matrix, we guarantee that the rotation part of the transformation matrix is actually on SO(3).
2. In trajectory optimization, we implement a class https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/optimization/quaternion_integration_constraint.h to encode the integration of quaternion satisfying the unit-length SO(3) constraint. Also you will need a unit quaternion constraint as in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/inverse_kinematics/unit_quaternion_constraint.h. I am adding more helper functions to make this class easier to use, if you have a really complicated robot with multiple floating bases and revolute joints. But I think for simple robots with a single floating base (like a quadrotor), this class should be ready for use.
   For a floating base in Drake, we use quaternion to represent its orientation, and angular velocity to represent its velocity.

It sounds like you are going to do gradient-based optimization. We have some interactive tutorials on that topic also (you could run these tutorials interactively in jupyter notebook). You could refer to https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/mathematical_program.ipynb as a starting point, and https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/nonlinear_program.ipynb for gradient-based nonlinear optimization. We also have some debugging tips for nonlinear optimization in the tutorial https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/debug_mathematical_program.ipynb. All tutorials are in the folder `drake/tutorials`, which you can find tutorials on other topics.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And Thanks a lot for the links. Clarifies a lot of things.

Comment: To expand on auto-diff for `pydrake`, the `dynamical_systems.ipynb` notebook Hongkai cited refers the following to enable conversion to `LeafSystem_[AutoDiffXd]` for a given pydrake system: https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.scalar_conversion.html#pydrake.systems.scalar_conversion.TemplateSystem

Comment: BTW, I made a mistake in my initial answer, that in simulation we DON'T project the quaternion back to the unit circle. I have updated my answer above.